# XML error with aws-mturk-clt-1.3.1 - cannot find element declaration

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

I've been using the aws-mturk-clt toolset for awhile.  I recently came back to my project, which had been working, but now when I attempt to submit HITs using the `loadHITs.sh` command I receive this error:

> [-1,-1] cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element
>   'ExternalQuestion'

As far as I can tell, nothing has changed in my project code and directory structure from when it used to work.  The XML schema is referenced in external_hit.question:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Note the inclusion of the $urls variable which is defined as a field 
in the input file.  Apache Velocity is the template engine that is used to 
perform the merging of variables into template files.  You can learn more 
about Velocity's capabilities at http://velocity.apache.org. -->
<ExternalQuestion xmlns="https://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd">
    <ExternalURL>http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/webpage.jsp</ExternalURL>
    <FrameHeight>600</FrameHeight>
</ExternalQuestion>
```

I checked the schema url, and the schema still exists and appears to be properly defined.

Let me know any further information required.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is I used https to reference the schema, due to a previously executed global search-replace.  When I reverted to http the problem disappeared:

```
<ExternalQuestion xmlns="http://mechanicalturk.amazonaws.com/AWSMechanicalTurkDataSchemas/2006-07-14/ExternalQuestion.xsd">
```